# MySQL into outfiles

Tags: mysql

I have trouble exporting a mySQL query result to a file in a specific folder. Here is what I did:

```
SELECT N1_Name,V_Name,N2_Name INTO OUTFILE '/home/user/Documents/result.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM Result;
```

I always get "ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/tle/Documents/PTQL_result.csv' (Errcode: 13)", which is permission denied error.
The query works if I use the default location or tmp.
I even chmod Documents to 777 but the mysql process still could not write to it.
Any ideas is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file will be create by the mysql user, so the mysql user needs write permission on the directory. It sounds like you've granted that permission.

The mysql user also needs execute permission on the higher-level directories, specifically this one:

```
/home/tle
```

I'm guessing the mysql user does not have execute permission on that directory. If you grant that permission it should work.

Comment: I did grant the execute permission on all upper directory. (All of them are set to 755). It is weird.

Comment: Try creating the file at the terminal to see if it fails: `sudo -u mysql touch /home/tle/Documents/PTQL_result.csv`

Comment: Yes. It creates the file successfully at the location