# PHP export MySQL tables to SQL file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run this php code:

```
<?php
    $sql="SHOW tables from integra_integra ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);

    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $backupFile='A_Backups_Full/'.$result[0].'.sql';
        $sql2="SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' from '".$result[0]."' ";
        $result2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);

        echo $result[0].' '.$backupFile.'<br><br>';
    }
?>
```

It selects all tables from a database and then runs a query to export each table to an sql file

When I echo the data, it displays fine so I know there is no problem there but it's not saving the .sql files.

I have given the directory they are saving to full access

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594138/mysql-into-outfiles?

Comment: change `$result2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);` to `$result2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));` - looks like you have syntax error

Comment: Right. It says access denied for user but I'm using the same connection string on other queries that work fine

Comment: MySQl needs to be in the group or owner of the file "$backupFile" because you are exporting from the MySQL process and not PHP...

Comment: @RaymondNijland how do I do that?